# Region property undetected in nested BorderContainer ContentPane widgets

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo-1.9

I'm working on creating a basic to-do list app using Dojo 1.9. I have a simple mockup of what I'd like an individual task to look like which can be seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msweeney/eMZsL/). I've tried to implement this in my to-do list, in the addTask function for this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msweeney/Qp885/).

Essentially, I have the following layout:

```
BorderContainer
    BorderContainer (top)
        Button (right)
    ContentPane (center)
        BorderContainer (task0)
            ContentPane (left)
                CheckBox
            ContentPane (center)
                InlineEditBox
            ContentPane (right)
                Button
        BorderContainer (task1)
            ...
        ...
```

and the BorderContainer widgets for the tasks (task0, task1, ...) are not formatting their children ContentPane widgets correctly -- inspection in Firebug shows that the dijitAlign* properties are not being set. Why is this? I'm calling startup on complete, and inspection of the DOM clearly shows that all children are being nested appropriately.

Comment: It looks like it works when you resize the task container. Adding `taskContainer.resize()` right below your startup call seems to make the task row look the same as in your single task jsfiddle. I will also note that resizing the window in your second fiddle (the actual task list) causes a single task row to take up all the space in the task list. Adding a second task list resizes correctly.

Comment: Beautiful; that worked. If you translate your comment into an answer and explain why this works, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling `resize` on your task container after you start it up. Because it's being placed into another `BorderContainer`, it needs to explicitly be resized in order to properly fit itself. You can also set explicit sizes on the `BorderContainer` and the `html` and `body` elements, but this isn't always ideal. It's still a good idea to explicitly resize after placing inside another `BorderContainer`. See [the note in the middle of this section of the documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/LayoutContainer.html#setting-sizes) on sizing `LayoutContainer`.